# PHP switch and case logical control

Tags: php, switch-statement

It possible to have logical control on case ?

ie:

```
$v = 0;
$s = 1;

switch($v)
{
    case $s < $v:
        // Do some operation
        break;
    case $s > $v:
        // Do some other operation
        break;
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar ?

Comment: Why do want to use switch ? Use if-else ladder instead.

Comment: For less complex code. Is more easy to me in current code to use wsitch

Comment: Why not try it and see for yourself?

Comment: I would suggest you do use if-else/elseif, not sure how it's simpler to use switch given that an if statement uses less code..

Comment: I have already test it. The problem is that I have many diferent states to test. So can I make logical control into case ?

Comment: I don't understand how using a construct for something it isn't intended for makes the code less complex or easier.

Comment: For all who comment "use if-elseif": Assume you have a continuous value, from 0-100, and you want to echo a value based on ranges (for example 0-9->echo A, 10-19->echo B, etc). The "elseif" is fuglier than the aforementioned switch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition that is passed to switch is a value the cases are compared against. The condition (in your question $v) is evaluated once and then PHP seeks for the first case that matches the result.

[From the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) (after Example #2), emphasis added:

> The switch statement executes line by line (actually, statement by statement). In the beginning, no code is executed. **Only when a case statement is found with a value that matches the value of the switch expression** does PHP begin to execute the statements. PHP continues to execute the statements until the end of the switch block, or the first time it sees a break statement.

In your question `switch ($v)` is same as if you'd written: `switch (0)`, because `$v = 0`. Then, your switch will try to find a case which equals to 0. And, just as [@Kris said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7792771/216129):

> $s < $v evaluates to false, which triggers on the $v because it is 0 in here.

---

If you have to use conditions in case statements, your switch-condition should be a boolean, e.g.:

```
$v = 0;
$s = 1;

switch (true) {
    case ($s < $v):
        echo 's is smaller than v';
    break;

    case ($s > $v):
        echo 's is bigger than v';
    break;
}
```

Now your switch tries to seek the first case that evaluates to `true`, which in this case would be `$s > $v`.

---

Note that while the switch-condition is evaluated only once, cases are each evaluated in order:

```
$a = 1;

switch ($a) {
    case 2:
        echo 'two';
        break;
    case (++$a > 2):
        break;
    default:
        echo $a;
}
```

echoes '2' from default-case, because when comparing $a to "2" $a was 1 and the case is discarded; while:

```
$a = 1;

switch ($a) {
    case (++$a > 2):
        break;
    case 2:
        echo 'two';
        break;

    default:
        echo $a;
}
```

echoes 'two' from case '2' because `++$a > 2` increases $a but doesn't match $a.

`default` is a fallback and its position doesn't matter.

NB: the aforementioned switches are fugly and esoteric and are only provided as a proof-of-example.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most readable use of, but yes you can.

Use if/else - if/elseif/else structure if you do need just a simple comparison.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work, every case needs to be a scalar value. in your example case it is even worse, it may seem to work but...

$s < $v evaluates to false, which triggers on the $v because it is 0 in here.

Answer (score -2):

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

```
if ($a > $b) {
    echo "a is bigger than b";
} elseif ($a == $b) {
    echo "a is equal to b";
} else {
    echo "a is smaller than b";
}
```